# jQuery UI Datepicker with date range,starting from current date

Tags: jquery-ui, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am creating functionality for hotel events and I used jQuery UI datepicker to input two fields,
event start date and event end date.

So, as it seems I want to make the input of start to current date, which means event start date can't be set to past date. So can you tell me how it is done with coding.

[for example datepicker shown in this demo](http://www.phpjabbers.com/hotels-booking-system/demo.php)

Answer (score 4):

`$('#input').datepicker({ minDate : new Date() });` will do it.

Take a look at an example, apologies, I cannot include the CSS file

http://jsfiddle.net/xVAfP/

Answer (score 0):

On script Jquery:

```
var dates = $( "#date_init, #date_final" ).datepicker({
   onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var option = this.id == "date_init" ? "maxDate" : "minDate",
        instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat ||
            $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
            selectedDate, instance.settings d
        );
        dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
    }

});
```

on input:

with PHP:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="date_final" id="date_final" value="<? echo  date('Y/m/d'); ?>" >
```

or you can use javascript to set the date on input.!

Bye.
www.estevaosoberano.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="tbStartDate" value="" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" id="tbEndDate" value="" disabled="disabled" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbStartDate").datepicker({            
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: '/Content/Calendar.png',
            buttonText: 'Click here (date)',
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var $endDate = $('#tbStartDate').datepicker('getDate');
                $endDate.setDate($endDate.getDate() + 1);
                $('#tbEndDate').datepicker('setDate', $endDate).datepicker("option", 'minDate', $endDate);
            },
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                //$("#StartDate").val($("#tbStartDate").val());
            }
        });

        $("#tbEndDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: '/Content/Calendar.png',
            buttonText: 'Click here (date)',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                //$("#EndDate").val($("#tbEndDate").val());
            }
        });

            var $endDate = $('#tbStartDate').datepicker('getDate');
            $endDate.setDate($endDate.getDate() + 1);
            $('#tbEndDate').datepicker('setDate', $endDate).datepicker("option", 'minDate', $endDate);
    });
</script>
```